# How browsers deal with ports?

Tags: web-server, http, port, network-protocols, protocols

Suppose I've a website created which is hosted, and running on port `5000`. Now you are on a web browser (let's say chrome) visits the webpage.

- so does chrome sends a request from your PC to my server like `mywebsite.com:5000` (as the site is listening to that port)?
- and how does the port 80 (for the HTTP request) gets accessed then?

I just want to know what goes behind the scenes. How ports work? How browsers and servers handle the ports and various protocols?

I'm trying to get the answer but couldn't get one, so your help is very much appreciated

**Update:**

I've found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1055281/do-web-browsers-use-different-outgoing-ports-for-different-tabs

And thank you for downvoting my question and that too without mentioning any reason why

Answer (score 2):

A browser uses the default ports 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS URLs *unless* you specify a port using the `:portnumber` suffix. For the syntax, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL.

Nearly all application-layer protocols have a default server-side port that is used when none other is specified by the user - see

- https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers